# Razor class library static web assets on different urls before and after publish when libman used

Tags: blazor, razor-class-library, libman

I use static web assets in razor class library, and they are on different paths on local run under VS and published final docker image.
In `JoinRpg.WebComponents` RCL there is `.\JoinRpg.WebComponents\wwwroot\lib\bootstrap-select\js\bootstrap-select.js` which is dynamically added to build using `Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager.Build` task.

In `JoinRpg.Portal` ASP.NET Core project which are reference `JoinRpg.WebComponents` using `ProjectReference`, this js file is:

- Local run: `/_content/JoinRpg.WebComponents/lib/bootstrap-select/js/bootstrap-select.js`
- Docker image: `/lib/bootstrap-select/js/bootstrap-select.js`

If it's not restored by `Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager.Build` they always be at correct path `/_content/JoinRpg.WebComponents`.

Adding  `if (env.IsDevelopment()) { StaticWebAssetsLoader.UseStaticWebAssets(env, Configuration); }` changes nothing.

I want js file be on the same URL on local and remote run.